# SPSite.BypassImpersonationStateCheck - a mystery showing up in Sharepoint error logs

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

In the process of tracking down an elusive Sharepoint custom workflow problem, I cranked up the verbosity level on our sandbox MOSS server and noticed the following error message start popping up:

> SPSite should not be used with mixed impersonation state. If you do want to cache an SPSite created within RunWithElevatedPrivileges, call SPSite.BypassImpersonationStateCheck

While this is most likely unrelated to our problem, I was curious about this SPSite.BypassImpersonationStateCheck method that doesn't seem to actually exist.  When we include this call in our code it won't compile.  MSDN doesn't have any information.  A quick Google search doesn't turn up any concrete answers.  What *is* SPSite.BypassImpersonationStateCheck?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in my logs. I cranked up the verbosity due to workflow failing in a load-balanced farm environment.

Comment: seems like error from previous version of SharePoint. Method maybe removed, but log message still exists

Comment: I've just had the same appear in Office 365 - from an event receiver in a Sandbox solution I'd written. Pretty weird; you can't impersonate in Sandbox...